# 403 Forbidden message when editing/saving text in editor

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, text-editor, http-status-code-403

I am working on a website and am using ckeditor as my text-editor. The problem is when i try to save the data in the editor instead of saving the data it shows 403 Forbidden message. I have searched the web for this problem with the editor but didn't find any solution. It works fine on local but the problem arises when its online. I have granted all the required access to the db user in my online database as well. But still it doesn't work! Please help me out!

Comment: This error is due to not enough permissions to page/editror where you are redirecting.

Comment: I have granted all the permissons to the db user.

Comment: Not only to db. You need to give permission to your whole project means all directories and files inside your project. This is common issue when project files are not having enough permission.

Comment: permission level 0765 can solve your problem.